# Create view that shows how much a student a spent

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I need to create a view like this:

```
STUDENT JANUARY FEBRUARY MARCH ........ DECEMBER
miki     10.23   23.23    0               0
Goku     10        0       0               0
```

I have a table `studentMovement(id_studentmovement,id_student,month,year,cost,date)` that represents every sigle cost for the student in this month and year. it contains the real cost that some students had done.

Another table is `Month(id_month)`, that has all month id `(January==1 February==2 etc)`.

Table `Students(id_student,name)`

Another view is `Years(id_year)`, it contains some year.

I want to get for a year, for all students in the table student(also the student that don't have outputs) and for all month(if there is an output in this month the value is 0) , I want get the sum all cost. SO my view is this

```
CREATE
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = "***" @"%" SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW "schema"."v_student_table" AS select
        "s"."id_student" AS "id_student",
        "s"."name" AS "name",
        "m"."id_month" AS "id_month",
        coalesce(sum("sm"."amount"),0) AS "amount",
        coalesce(month("sm"."date"),"month"."id_month") AS "month",
        coalesce(year("sm"."date"),"year"."id_year") AS "anno"
    from
        ((("schema"."studentMovement" "sm"
    left join "schema"."students" "s" on "s"."id_student"="sm"."id_student")
    left join "schema"."month" "m" on "m"."id_month"="sm".id_month")
    inner join "schema"."years" "y" on "y"."id_year"="sm".id_year")

    group by
        coalesce(year("sm"."date"),"year"."id_year"),
         coalesce(month("sm"."date"),"month"."id_month"),
    "s"."id_student",
        "s"."name",
        "m"."id_month"
```

The problem is if there isn't a cost for a month in a year, I need to put 0 like value but with this query it doesn't do this.
the problem is the studentMovement has the real outputs. in the example above Goku has only one cost that is in jenuary but the student goku is not present for FEBRUARY etc, Anyone can help me?

Comment: Your query does not produce the "months across the top" output you require either. Is your problem that your query doesn't produce a 0 for months where there is no expenditure, doesn't produce months across the top, or both?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)
. That said, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select year(sm.date) as year, s.id_student, s.name,
       sum(amount) as year_amount,
       sum(case when month(sm.date) = 1 then amount else 0 end) as january,
       sum(case when month(sm.date) = 2 then amount else 0 end) as february,
       . . .
       sum(case when month(sm.date) = 12 then amount else 0 end) as december,
        "m"."id_month" AS "id_month",
        coalesce(sum("sm"."amount"),0) AS "amount",
from schema.students s join
     schema.studentMovement sm 
     on s.d_student = sm.id_student 
group by year(sm.date) as year, s.id_student, s.name;
```

The `. . .` is the logic for the remaining months.

Comment: your solution is correct for this case, but I have another case, is it better write here or create another post?

Comment: @poopp . . . Better to ask another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472339/how-resolve-null-value-when-create-view