# How resolve null value when create view

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I need to create a view like this:

```
STUDENT JANUARY FEBRUARY MARCH ........ DECEMBER
miki     10.23   23.23    0               0
Goku     10        0       0               0
 Luffy    0       0        0               0
```

I have a table `studentMovement(id_studentmovement,id_student,month,year,cost,date,id_university,university_name)`

that represents every sigle cost for the student in this month and year. it contains the real cost that some students had done in a certain course in a certain university.

```
Table Students(id_student,name)

Table University(id_university,university name);
```

I want to get for all university, all student  and for single student the cost for every months ( also if the student doesn't spent anything in a certain university:

This sql query is this:

```
select year(sm.date) as year, s.id_student, s.name,
       sum(amount) as year_amount,
       sum(case when month(sm.date) = 1 then amount else 0 end) as january,
       sum(case when month(sm.date) = 2 then amount else 0 end) as february,
       . . .
       sum(case when month(sm.date) = 12 then amount else 0 end) as december,


       u.id_university as id_university,
       u.university_name as university_name
from ((schema.students s left join
     schema.studentMovement sm 
     on s.d_student = sm.id_student ) inner join schema.university u on u.id_university=sm.id_university) 

group by year(sm.date) as year, s.id_student, s.name,  u.id_university,
       u.university_name
```

THe query put wrong value and some value are null.Anyone can help me?

Comment: What values are `NULL`?

Comment: id_university and university name !

Answer (score 0):

Try just using inner joins in the `from` clause:

```
FROM schema.students s JOIN
     schema.studentMovement sm 
     ON s.d_student = sm.id_student JOIN
     schema.university u
     ON u.id_university = sm.id_university
```

Comment: I just do in the example above and it doesn't work! :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you noticed some wrong values in the amount field: try to delete the double quotes

```
COALESCE(SUM(sm.amount), 0) AS amount,
```

Answer (score 0):

`Null` values appear from your do `Left Join` Statement. Because it returns all records from the `left table`, and the matched records from the `right table`. The result is `NULL` from the right side, if there is no match.

```
select 
   year(sm.date) as year, 
   s.id_student, 
   s.name,
   sum(amount) as year_amount,
   sum(case when month(sm.date) = 1 then amount else 0 end) as january,
   sum(case when month(sm.date) = 2 then amount else 0 end) as february,
   . . .
   sum(case when month(sm.date) = 12 then amount else 0 end) as december,
   u.id_university as id_university,
   u.university_name as university_name
from 
  ((schema.students s 
    inner join schema.studentMovement sm on s.d_student = sm.id_student ) 
         inner join schema.university u on u.id_university=sm.id_university) 
group by 
   year(sm.date), 
   s.id_student, 
   s.name,  
   u.id_university,
   u.university_name
```

If you want to not see `Null` change your `Left Join` to `Inner Join` instead because `Inner Join` selects records that have matching values in both tables.